# Enviar datos de PhoneGap a Web Service

Tags: javascript, webservice, rest, cordova, phonegap

estoy creando una app con Phonegap y no se como enviar un string desde mi .js a un web service que tengo creado con Java, alguna sugerencia soy nueva en esto y no encuentro nada claro, gracias.
Mi funcion JSON es la siguiente

```
myfuncion: function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("login").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;     
}
```

Podría hacer un post con Ajax desde aquí  así:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/HelloSpringMVC/hello",
  data: {x} ,
  )};
```

No entiendo sise puede usar así $.ajax y pasar la variable x.

Comment: Puedes usaj JQuery Ajax has probado? Muestra parte de lo que tengas hecho o de como lo estas haciendo

Comment: Agregué la forma en la que estoy intentándolo, el código $.ajax puedo ponerlo dentro de la función anterior?? Estoy comenzando y estoy un poco perdida, gracias @HectorLara

Comment: Claro que puedes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero : realicé un pequeño cambio en la función myfuncion para que retorne el valor de x.

```js
function myfuncion() {
  var x = document.getElementById("login").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "El texto demo es : " + x;
  return x;
}

$('#btn').click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        // Nombre de la propiedad que que recibe el valor de x en el backend
        nombreprodiedad: myfuncion()
    },
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/HelloSpringMVC/hello/' + myfuncion(),
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      // Hacer algo con la respuesta
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="login" placeholder="Escribe un numero">
<div id="demo"></div>
<button id="btn">Probar</button>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me sirvio su ayuda1